# How to redefine default macros of document class

Tags: header-footer, document-classes, blank-page

When choosing a document class, I find they all generate some unwanted change to my document, but I'm having trouble changing the default macros to set the formatting right.

In my preamble I'm running the following:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{  
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{Confidential}  
    \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage}  
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}  
}
```

This has the desired effect when using the `book` document class, but this class unfortunately also leaves a blank page after each chapter finishes, which I'd rather do without. This second issue can be solved by changing the class to `report`, but this then ruins the footer formatting by fixing 'Confidential' on the right and the  page number on the left of the footer.

Is there a command I can use to either:
- remove the blank page after each section in the book class, or;
- stop the report class from forcing the footer to not alternate as I've tried to make it?

Thanks

Comment: A blank page is added only when a chapter ends on an odd-numbered page. You can simply add the option `openany` to the `\documentclass` call. Actually the calls `\documentclass[openany]{book}` and `\documentclass[twoside]{report}` give very similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MWE would help, but my guess is you have left out the `twoside` option in report

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{Confidential}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}%
  \lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}%
```